# Android WebView getElementById('math') not working Dynamically

Tags: javascript, android, webview, innerhtml, mathjax

I have one `WebView` in that i have loaded [MathJax.js](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=default) using following code.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("","<script type='text/javascript' "
                  + "src="+ url +"></script>"
                  + "<span id='math'></span>"
                  /** 
                    I want set text dynamically for above span tag
                    using following script.
                   **/
                  + "<script type='text/javascript'>"
                  + "document.getElementById(\"math\").innerHTML='\\\\["+doubleEscapeTeX(question.getQuestion())+"\\\\]';"
                  + "</script>","text/html","utf-8","");
```

I want set text dynamically for above `<span>` tag using following `<script>`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   document.getElementById(\"math\").innerHTML='\\\\"+doubleEscapeTeX(question.getQuestion())+"\\\\]';"
</script>
```

How can i set again with `WebView`?

> In short, i want to load javascript only once and other content load dynamically every time.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
"$(function() { ... });"
```

or

```
 "$(document).ready(function() { ... });".

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById(\"math\").innerHTML='\\\\"+doubleEscapeTeX(question.getQuestion())+"\\\\]';"
   });
</script>
```